# Regular value -convergence

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

A smooth family of maps $ F^T: X \rightarrow Y $ converges in $ C^1 $ topology to a smooth map $ F : X \rightarrow Y $ 
as $ T \rightarrow \infty $. 0 is a regular value of a map $F $. Under which conditions is $ 0 $ 
a regular value of the maps $ F^T $ for $ T $ sufficiently large?

Answer (score 2):

If  $X$ is compact  the conclusion is true. If $X$ is not compact   then  the conclusion may not be true. A counterexample is  depicted  below

[image]

In this example  $Y\cong \mathbb{R}$ is the vertical axis and $X\cong \mathbb{R}$ is the curve.  $F_T$ is the projection $(x,y)\to y$. The  curve $X$ is obtained from the  graph of $y=1/x$  by a finger move: push down a small arc of this hyperbola until it touches the  horizontal  axis tangentially at  $T$.